# Angular: Display time in template with mask using a pipe

Tags: angular, time, angular-material, pipe, ngx-mask

I have this pipe, `secondsToHms`, to **convert from seconds to hours, minutes and seconds**:

```js
transform(seconds: number): string {
  const minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60); //minutes
  const secs = seconds % 60; //seconds
  const hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60); //hours
  const mins = minutes % 60; //minutes

  return (
    '' +
    (hours < 10 ? hours.toString().padStart(2, '0') : hours.toString()) +
    mins.toString().padStart(2, '0') +
    secs.toString().padStart(2, '0')
  );
}
```

In my HTML, I'm trying to display the value like this, but the time doesn't display as I want (HH:mm:ss) and I don't know why. I'm using [ngx-mask](https://github.com/JsDaddy/ngx-mask) inside the input.

```html
<ng-template [ngIf]="control.value.type === 'TYPE1'">
   <div class="input-group mb-2">
     <input
       (ngModelChange)="setDirty(true)"
       formControlName="quantity"
       type="text"
       class="form-control text-center"
       placeholder="00:00:00"
       mask="00:m0:s0"
      [value]="control.value.quantity | secondsToHms"
     />
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

The `control` variable is accessing in the template via this loop:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let control of dataArr.controls; 
  let i = index">
```

And this is the `dataArr` function:

```js
get dataArr() {
  return this.myForm.get('allData') as FormArray;
}
```

I need to do the conversion in the template since the pipe only applies when type is equal to *TYPE1* which only happens here `[ngIf]="control.value.type === 'TYPE1'"`.

I'm using this function to create form controls, don't know if it's relevant to this case.

```js
addDataFormGroup(data: DataModel) {
  this.dataArr.push(
    this.fb.group({
      data: data.data,
      dataType: data.dataType,
      quantity: data.quantity,
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: You mentioned that the time doesn't display as you want. Can you please add how it displays now(current behavior)

Comment: Yes, If the current value of the quantity is 49 seconds, for example, it display only 49 and not 00:00:49

Answer (score 0):

there're several errors in your code.

1. The mask that use ngx-mask should be: `00:00:00`
2. When you use ReactiveForms (formControlName) you should **not** use
   `value`. You need give value to the formControl -using patchValue or
   setValue-, so to give value you use a simple function, not a pipe
3. You can make more compact your function

   ```
   transform(seconds: number):string {   
       const minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60); //minutes  
       const secs = seconds % 60; //seconds   const hours =
       Math.floor(minutes / 60); //hours   const mins = minutes % 60;
       //minutes

         return ('00'+hours).slice(-2)+":"+
                ('00'+mins).slice(-2)+":"+
                ('00'+secs).slice(-2) }

   //and you use addDataFormGroup(data: DataModel) {
        this.dataArr.push(
           this.fb.group({
             data: data.data,
             dataType: data.dataType,
             quantity: this.transform(data.quantity), //<--here
           })   
         ); }
   ```

**Update** As the trasnformations depend from a variable we can take another appoach that is use [ngModel] and (ngModelChange) to mannage a formControl.

Imagine a functions like:

```
  transform(seconds: number|string): string {
    if (typeof(seconds)=="string")
      return seconds;
    const minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60); //minutes
    const secs = seconds % 60; //seconds
    const hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60); //hours
    const mins = minutes % 60; //minutes
  
    return ('00'+hours).slice(-2)+":"+
           ('00'+mins).slice(-2)+":"+
           ('00'+secs).slice(-2)
  }
  parse(value:string)
  {
    const match=value.match(/\d\d/g)
    if (match && match.length==3)
      return (+match[0])*3600+(+match[1]*60)+(+match[2])
    return value
  }
```

We can use some like

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div formArrayName="dataArray">
    <div *ngFor="let group of dataArray.controls;let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
    <input [ngModel]="transform(form.get('dataArray.'+i+'.quantity').value)"
           (ngModelChange)="form.get('dataArray.'+i+'.quantity')
                                .setValue(parse($event))"

           [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}"
    />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

See that we use [ngModel] to show the value of the formControl and ngModelChange to change the value of the formControl. Perhafs it's necesary some ajust when (blur) the input

You have a litle stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-doz7mu?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: Okay, I got it, but in my case I need to use the pipe because the data depends on a select so I cannot apply the `secondsToHms` function (or pipe) to all the quantities.

Comment: @jgcarrillo, thre're a nother option that it's use [ngModel] and (ngModelChange) to mannage the FormControl. I just updated the answer

Comment: Thanks very much for the help but with that approach I cannot watch the `ng-dirty` class so although I submit the form, the input still remain dirty.

Comment: @jgcarrillom a formControl exist even there're no input with formcontrolName. I imagine you can add to the input with ngModel some like [ngClass]="{'ng-dirty':form.get('dataArray.'+i+'.quantity').dirty,'ng-touched':form.get('dataArray.'+i+'.quantity').touched...}" But I'm not pretty sure about this

Comment: I think I can't. I have tried before with that solution and the input is still dirty.